# How to predict with tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I trained a tensorflow model and it has a decent accruacy, however when I try and get it to predict  by passing in an image. I get the following error

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'conv2d_12' (type Conv2D).
    
    Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 3 from 1 for '{{node sequential_6/conv2d_12/Conv2D}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](sequential_6/ExpandDims, sequential_6/conv2d_12/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,28,1,1], [3,3,1,32].
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'conv2d_12' (type Conv2D):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 28, 1, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Below is the model summary

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_12 (Conv2D)          (None, 26, 26, 32)        320       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_12 (MaxPoolin  (None, 13, 13, 32)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_13 (Conv2D)          (None, 11, 11, 64)        18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_13 (MaxPoolin  (None, 5, 5, 64)         0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 flatten_6 (Flatten)         (None, 1600)              0         
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_12 (Bat  (None, 1600)             6400      
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 dense_12 (Dense)            (None, 256)               409856    
                                                                 
 dropout_6 (Dropout)         (None, 256)               0         
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_13 (Bat  (None, 256)              1024      
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 dense_13 (Dense)            (None, 25)                6425      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 442,521
Trainable params: 438,809
Non-trainable params: 3,712
_________________________________________________________________
```

I have tried processing it with the following function. But I get the error

```
img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(
    '/content/drive/MyDrive/Datasets/A.png', target_size=(28, 28)
)

img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0) 

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])`
```

Comment: Kindly verify the model architecture is correctly defined to handle input images with shape (28,28,1).
The model is expecting grayscale images with a shape of (28,28,1), but the input image your passing in seems to have been loaded as a color image with 3 channels. It’s causing the input shape mismatch.